# Index was out of range. Must be non negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexing

I have looked at about 20 of these other posts for help and none of them seem to be what I am looking for. I have included everything below. I have tried making it equal to i but I still get the index error. The db I'm working on won't always have info in it. How I can I make this to return even when there is nothing in the db?

```
List<DataClassLibrary.LineData> ScaleGroup1and3 = list.FindAll(ld => ld.ScaleGroup == DataClassLibrary.ScaleGroup.GROUP_1 ||
                                                            ld.ScaleGroup == DataClassLibrary.ScaleGroup.BOTH);

    List<DataClassLibrary.LineData> ScaleGroup2and3 = list.FindAll(ld => ld.ScaleGroup == DataClassLibrary.ScaleGroup.GROUP_2 ||
                                                        ld.ScaleGroup == DataClassLibrary.ScaleGroup.BOTH);

    Label[] Group1and3ItemLabels = new Label[8] { L1, L7, L13, L19, L25, L31, L37, L43 };
    Label[] Group1and3BrandLabels = new Label[8] { L2, L8, L14, L20, L26, L32, L38, L44 };
    Label[] Group1and3RacksLabels = new Label[8] { L3, L9, L15, L21, L27, L33, L39, L45 };
    Label[] Group1and3CasesLabels = new Label[8] { L50, L51, L53, L55, L57, L59, L61, L63};

    Label[] Group2and3ItemLabels = new Label[] { L4, L10, L16, L22, L28, L34, L40, L46 };
    Label[] Group2and3BrandLabels = new Label[] { L5, L11, L17, L23, L29, L35, L41, L47 };
    Label[] Group2and3rackslabels = new Label[] { L6, L12, L18, L24, L30, L36, L42, L48 };
    Label[] Group2and3CasesLabels = new Label[] { L49, L52, L54, L56, L58, L60, L62, L64 };

    for (int i = 0; i <= ScaleGroup1and3.Count; i++)
    {
            Group1and3ItemLabels[i].Text = list[i].ItemCode;
            Group1and3BrandLabels[i].Text = list[i].BrandCode;
            Group1and3CasesLabels[i].Text = list[i].CasesRemaining.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= ScaleGroup2and3.Count; i++)
    {
        Group2and3ItemLabels[i].Text = list[i].ItemCode;
        Group2and3BrandLabels[i].Text = list[i].BrandCode;
        Group2and3CasesLabels[i].Text = list[i].CasesRemaining.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: On which line does the error appear?

Comment: i <= ScaleGroup2and3.Count should probably be i < ScaleGroup2and3.Count

Comment: @Plue Group1and3ItemLabels[i].Text = list[i].ItemCode;

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos: I have 8 elements, 0 - 7. Loop through 0 - 8 == crash. This doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Magus your saying that 0-7 works but when it hits 8 it crashes

Comment: Lets count! 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 = 8. We have 8 elements. Lets get element 8! Oh wait, the eighth element is named 7.

Comment: @Magus I got that part lol so your saying i need to make Label[] Group1and3ItemLabels = new Label[8] { L1, L7, L13, L19, L25, L31, L37, L43 }; 7 instead?

Comment: No, I'm saying what @NiklasArbin said. You can't index element 8 when the last one is element 7. You have 8 elements, but the first one is 0. If you go up from 0 to one less than count (< rather than <=), you still access all 8, but you don't try to access anything that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<=` to `<` so that loops are not executed when DB returned nothing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScaleGroup1and3.Count; i++)
...
for (int i = 0; i < ScaleGroup2and3.Count; i++)
```

You actually need to change them anyway, since index in lists is 0-based, meaning that element

```
ScaleGroup1and3[ScaleGroup1and3.Count]
```

does not exist.

Comment: Will that be able to return when there is only one record?

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos, yes. This one record will have index 0, while `Count` will be 1, meaning that loop will execute exactly one iteration for i equal to 0.

Comment: What if I equals one? I had to adjust it when there was only one record in the db because count and index = 1.

Comment: But i wont equal 1, because it's a strict less than, rather than a less than or equal to. i only ever reaches 0 if count is 1.

Comment: Count and index will never be 1 at the same time. If the count is 1 then there is only one element in your collection, and it will be at index 0.

Comment: @Mashton weird cause earlier that was the only way it would work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `ScaleGroup1and3` and `ScaleGroup2and3` have **no more than 8 elements**, and the `for` declaration should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScaleGroup1and3.Count; i++)

for (int i = 0; i < ScaleGroup2and3.Count; i++)
```

Comment: The db can have thousands of values I just need the top eight hence Label[] Group1and3ItemLabels = new Label[8] { L1, L7, L13, L19, L25, L31, L37, L43 };